# How to use Spring Integration to have consumers pick up only one message from a queue?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, partitioning

Im trying to implement remote partitioning in Spring batch using Spring integration with one RabbitMQ queue, and two JVMs. In the first JVM, there's a master and one salve running, and in the second JVM, there's another slave running. The goal is to have the master send two messages to the queue, and have the slaves pick up only one message each.

Here's everything I tried:

- **Test1**: Event driven consumers with a direct channel and with the default acknowledgement mode (AUTO)
- **Result**: Both slaves were picking up both messages at the same time, and messages were staying on the queue until the processing transaction is completed.

  ---
- **Test2**: Event driven consumers with a direct channel and acknowledgement mode NONE
- **Result**: Both messages were picked up by one slave immediately, and the second slave doesn’t see any messages.

  ---
- **Test3**: Polling consumers with a queue channel and MaxMessagesPerPoll set to 1, and one minute polling interval. I tried using all acknowledgement modes and got the same result.
- **Result**: Both messages were picked up by one slave and processed with a one minute waiting period between them, and the second slave doesn’t see any messages. I was at least expecting to see one message in the queue  during the one-minute waiting period, but for some reason I didn’t see any messages in the queue.

Can someone explain this behavior, and do you have any ideas of how I can have each slave pick up only one message?

Also, I'm wondering if there's a way in Spring Batch Partitioning and Spring integration to send the two messages to two separate queues. This seems to be the cleaner solution so we don’t have to deal with these conflicts between the slaves.

Comment: **Test1** should work. It's impossible for two consumers on the same queue to get the same message. You should not need 2 queues. Show your configuration. Edit the question; don't try to put it in a comment, it won't render well. **Test2** - using NONE (auto ack in RabbitMQ terminology) risks message loss. Your observation may be due to prefetch. **Test3** Using a queue channel also risks message loss in the event of a failure. Again, prefetch might cause both messages going to the same consumer. You can reduce prefetch to 1 at the cost of performance.

Comment: Setting PrefetchCount to 1 seems to be working. Thanks!